# Adding Twitter Bootstrap to CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed website using CodeIgniter that uses MySQL to populate a results page. I would now like to improve all the pages appearances and most places recommend using Bootstrap. I have tried to add Bootstrap to my CodeIgniter project but with no success.

Does anyone know of an up-to-date guide I could follow to complete this?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/sjlu/CodeIgniter-Bootstrap

Answer (score 18):

A simple way would be to use [Bootstrap CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/). For CSS, simply include this line in the `<head>` section of every webpage (somewhere in your view files, depending on how you have structured them):

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Bootstrap's plugins depend on jQuery, so you'll need to include jQuery before Bootstrap's JavaScript:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Simple example page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Your great site!</title>
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Alternatively you could host the files on your web server. Upload the relevant files to a publicly accessible directory. I'm going to assume that they are in an assets folder, in your web root, like this:

```
+-- public_html
|  +-- index.php
|  +-- assets
|  |  +-- css
|  |  |  +-- boostrap.css
|  |  +-- js
|  |  |  +-- bootstrap.js
|  |  |  +-- jquery.js
|  (other files/directories...)
```

To include them in your view files, you can link them like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>">

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/jquery.js"); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/bootstrap.js"); ?>"></script>
```

You'll need to have loaded the [URL Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) to use the `base_url()` function.

Comment: i have included them (if i click them in chrome web inspector i go too the right file) but i cant get my dropdown menu to dropdown. copied 10 diffrent ones so im sure its not the html

Comment: The dropdowns function using a jQuery plugin. Have you included jQuery?

Comment: No worries, I've edited the answer to show that jQuery is required.

Comment: What about fonts/ directory?

Answer (score 1):

First time using PHP CodeIgniter , Bootstrap  and Bitnami mampstack.
( All develope code in local notebook)

**1. To extract** the file CodeIgniter 3.x and Boostrap 3.x(Twitter)
Here my directory :

```
    /Applications/mampstack-5.4.26-2/apache2/htdocs/TestCoceIginter_Bootstra
    /Applications/mampstack-5.4.26-2/apache2/htdocs/TestCoceIginter_Bootstrap/application
    /Applications/mampstack-5.4.26-2/apache2/htdocs/TestCoceIginter_Bootstrap/assets
```

**2.Modification (Add)**

a. **application/controller/Welcome.php**

```
    <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Welcome extends CI_Controller 
    {
    public function __construct() { 
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url');

    public function index(){
            $this->load->view('welcome_message');
            }
    }
```

b.**application/views/welcome_message.php**

```
    <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/jquery.min.js"); ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/bootstrap.js"); ?>"></script>   
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to remove the 'index.php' from url like in the official example then you should try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the config.php in `/CodeIgniter/application/config` directory,

And edit it as:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_folder/';
```