# how to link bootstrap with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I need to connect css styles to codegniter using bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo site_url('css/bootstrap.css'); ?>">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Twitter Bootstrap to CodeIgniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843265/adding-twitter-bootstrap-to-codeigniter)

Comment: You may find [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20846341/604532) useful.

Comment: simple solution, use `base_url()` instead of `site_url()`

Comment: Just going chime in here and inform you that codeignighter is dead and you should consider going to laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep all the static files outside application folder.
Suppose you have a folder named `static` along with `application` and `system` folder. So you can keep all your static files in that folder and then link the files as `'static/css/style.css'`

Answer (score 1):

Create one Assets folder in root and add JS CSS and images In that folder and add assets files in your page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

create assest folder in root and add **assest/css/bootstrap.min.css** then add style

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo site_url('assest/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you create Assets folder and inside create css folder then include the file bootstrap.min.css . below the code include your view and download the bootstrap css.

```
<link href="<?= base_url("Assets/css/bootstrap.min.css")?>" rel="stylesheet">
```